# Как сделать div по размеру img?

Tags: html, css

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы div#imgcont был по размеру равен img, при этом width и height у изображения были заданы в css 30%?

```html
<div id="content" >
     <div id="imgcont"><img src="1.jpg"></div>
     <p>Sometext</p>
</div>
```

Comment: поясните чего вы хотите в размер а что в 30%, а то не состыкуется...

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин изменил в вопросе

Comment: можно сделать .imgcont { display: inline-block; } тогда он по идее будет в размер изображения

Comment: Я тоже сначала подумал о display: inline-block, но он становится по длине равным браузеру (я не знаю почему)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Красный блок имеет размеры ровно в картинку, тестируем кнопкой "показать/спрятать".

```js
function toggle() {
  document.getElementById('image1').classList.toggle('hidden');
  return false;
}
```

```css
.red {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  line-height: 0;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="return toggle();">показать/спрятать</a>

<br/>

<div class="red"><img id="image1" src="http://dosaaf34-tr.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/1-31-300x184.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: Честно говоря, не очень понял

Comment: @igor_bal упросил и добавил пример для сравнения

Comment: @igor_bal сделал пример ещё нагляднее

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @igor_bal если ответ вам подошёл отметьте его лайком и ответом.

Comment: а где размер изображения в процентах?

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev так а где можно 30% указать, если его укажешь, то они будут от родительского тега, а значит родительский уже не сможет быть в его размер, можно только просто в пикселях указать

Comment: Можно через JavaScript сделать что бы внешний тег был 100% в размер картинки а сама картинка в 30%. Но это уже будет не через CSS

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин просто вопрос задан совсем иначе, чем на него ответили.

Answer (score 3):

Это можно реализовать так... Задать `img` в место процентов `30vw`, а родителю 
`width: max-content;`

О поддержке браузерами можно посмотреть [тут](https://caniuse.com/#search=max-content)

```css
#imgcont {
  margin: 0;
  width: max-content;
  border: 4px solid black;
}

img {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="imgcont"><img src="https://www.1zoom.ru/big2/34/322924-alexfas01.jpg"></div>
  <p>Sometext</p>
</div>
```